# Правильный вывод кто онлайн

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста у меня есть друзья, и вывод кто онлайн, а кто оффлайн.Но у меня выводит всех и кто онлайн и кто оффлайн. Вот код вывода друзей кто онлайн подправте пожалуйста что бы выводилось только кто онлайн.

```
<?php

$frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one='$myrow2[id]' OR user_two='$myrow2[id]' ORDER BY id DESC ");

while ($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)){

  $user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
  $user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];
    if ($user_one == $myrow2['id']) {
      $id = $user_two;
    } else{

    $id = $user_one;
    }
    $username = getuser($id, 'username');
    $family = getuser($id,'family');
    $avatar = getuser($id,'avatar');
    $city = getuser($id,'city');
    ?>

<div id='pd-fr'>
<div class='foo'>
 <a href='/id<? echo $id ?>'>
 <img src='/<? echo  $avatar ?>' width=130px height=130px border=0px>
<div class='fr-us-fm2'><? echo "$username <br> $family" ?>

    <?php 
//Олнайн офлайн начало
$userinfo = mysql_query("SELECT lastdate FROM `users` WHERE id='$id'"); 
$userinfodat = mysql_fetch_array($userinfo);

$today = date("U"); 
if($userinfodat['lastdate'] + 100 < $today) { 
echo "<div class='offlineStatus'></div>"; 
} else { 
echo "<div class='onlineStatus'></div>"; 
}; 
//Олнайн офлайн конец
?>
 </div>
<div class='cit'><? echo  $city ?>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Пока у вас в базе данных не будет отметок о том, кто и когда заходил (как минимум), эта задача нереализуема. Каждый запрос к веб-серверу атомарен; пользователь на самом деле считается "онлайн" только до того момент, пока сервер не перешлет ему ответ на его запрос.

Comment: У меня есть кто и когда заходил все работает кто онлайн и кто оффлайн, просто нужно выввести именно кто онлайн.

Comment: А что для Вас онлайн? пользователь в браузере открыл страницу и смотрит на нее? а если в этот момент у провайдера упал канал и у пользователя "нет интернета" (специально взято в кавычки), то он онлайн для сайта или оффлайн? (пользователь ещё ничего не знает).

Comment: Плане того когда пользователь заходит.В бд заносится время захода дата и это обновляется каждую минуту, когда человек без действует записывается в бд последний заход когда он был активен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перечитал код и вопрос еще раз и думаю, я понял вопрос. Вот код

```
<?php

$frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one='$myrow2[id]' OR user_two='$myrow2[id]' ORDER BY id DESC ");

while ($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)){

  $user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
  $user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];
  if ($user_one == $myrow2['id']) {
    $id = $user_two;
  } else{
    $id = $user_one;
  }
  $username = getuser($id, 'username');
  $family = getuser($id,'family');
  $avatar = getuser($id,'avatar');
  $city = getuser($id,'city');

  //Олнайн офлайн начало
  $userinfo = mysql_query("SELECT lastdate FROM `users` WHERE id='$id'"); 
  $userinfodat = mysql_fetch_array($userinfo);

  $today = date("U");
  if($userinfodat['lastdate'] + 100 < $today) {
    continue;
  }

echo <<<HTML
<div id='pd-fr'>
<div class='foo'>
 <a href='/id$id'>
 <img src='/$avatar' width=130px height=130px border=0px>
<div class='fr-us-fm2'>$username <br> $family
<div class='onlineStatus'></div>
</div>
<div class='cit'>$city</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
HTML;
}
?>
```

Логику и вывод нужно разделять, тогда синтаксис будет проще. В обновленном примере в первой половине while  получение данных, а в второй - вывод. Это не идеальное решение, но оно сильно лучше предыдущего.

Comment: Извините он мне вот пишет Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in у меня  кто онлайн и оффлайн находится в таблице users

Comment: похоже, я не все удалил... поправил ответ.

Comment: @KoVadim Все заработало спасибо вам огромное за помощь.